# I'm getting an error when installing Angular Material in Nx workspace

Tags: angular, angular-material, nrwl-nx, nx-workspace

I'm creating an Angular and React project using Nx monorepo workspace. The problem arises when I try to install Angular Material using `npm i @angular/material`
I'm currently using Angular v16.
Here's the error i'm getting:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: jua-code@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@15.2.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"~15.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/animations@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from @angular/material@16.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!   @angular/material@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Below is my package.json file contents:

```
{
  "name": "jua-code",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {},
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~15.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@nrwl/angular": "^16.0.0",
    "@nrwl/react": "^16.0.0",
    "@nx/cypress": "16.0.0",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "16.0.0",
    "@nx/jest": "16.0.0",
    "@nx/js": "16.0.0",
    "@nx/linter": "16.0.0",
    "@nx/react": "16.0.0",
    "@nx/web": "16.0.0",
    "@nx/webpack": "16.0.0",
    "@nx/workspace": "^16.0.0",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.7",
    "@schematics/angular": "~15.2.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.1.2",
    "@swc/cli": "~0.1.62",
    "@swc/core": "~1.3.51",
    "@testing-library/react": "14.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/node": "18.14.2",
    "@types/react": "18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.58.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.58.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.1",
    "cypress": "^12.2.0",
    "eslint": "~8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "jest": "^29.4.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.1",
    "jest-preset-angular": "~13.0.0",
    "nx": "16.0.0",
    "nx-cloud": "latest",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "react-refresh": "^0.10.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~15.2.0",
    "@swc/helpers": "~0.5.0",
    "blurhash": "^2.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "firebase": "^9.21.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.16",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-blurhash": "^0.3.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  }
}
```

I've tried tweaking the packages versions but to no avail. Any help is much appreciated

I know that you need to run `npm i @angular/material` then `npx nx g @angular/material:ng-add --project=my-project-name` but won't work unless the first command completes.
Sometimes I also get the following error: `cannot find module adapter/compat`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly install your angular material version (15.2) with `npm i @angular/material@15.2`